# Modify methods so they are given an array index value of the moon whose name or radius is required

Tags: processing

So the part of my question is ''Modify getMoonName() and getMoonRadius() so they are given an array index value of the moon whose name or radius is required.''
I've tried adding moons[i].getRadius but then end up getting ''The variable i does not exist''. Here's the code.
PLANET CLASS

```java
    public class Planet
    {
      private float angle=0.01;
      // add class member variables here
      private String name;
      private float radius;
      private float distance;
      private float speed;
      private Moon[] moons;


      // add constructor here
      public Planet(String n, float r, float d, float s, Moon[] m)
      {
        this.name=n;
        this.radius=r;
        this.distance=d;
        this.speed=s;
        this.moons=m;
      }

      // add other methods here
      public String getName()
      {
        return name;
      }

      public float getRadius()
      {
        return radius;
      }

      public float getDistance()
      {
        return distance;
      }

      public float getSpeed()
      {
        return speed;
      }

      public Moon[] getMoons()
      {
        return moons;
      }

      public void setRadius(float r)
      {
        this.radius=r;
      }


      public String getMoonName()
      {
        return moons[i].getName();
      }

      public float getMoonRadius()
      {
        return moons[i].getRadius();
      }

      public String toString()
      {
        int n=0;
        for  (int i=0; i<moons.length; i++)
        {
          n++;
        }
        return "Planet" + name + ("Radius: " +radius +"Distance: " +distance) +n +"moons.";
      } 

      public void printMoons()
      {
        for  (int i=0; i<moons.length; i++)
        {
          System.out.println(moons[i]);
        }
      }


      // This will display the moon when other code is completed.  You don't need to understand this code.
     public void display()
     {  
     angle=angle+(0.01*speed);
     pushMatrix();
      rotate(angle);
      translate(distance,0);
      fill(255, 255, 255);
      ellipse(0, 0, radius*2, radius*2);    

      for(Moon moon: getMoons())
        moon.display();

        popMatrix();    
      }
    }`
```

MOON CLASS

```
public class Moon
    {
      private float angle=0.01;
      // add class member variables here
      private String name;
      private float radius;
      private float distance;
      private float speed;
      private int orbitalPeriod;


      // add constructor here
      public Moon(String n, float r, float d, float s, int o)
      {
        this.name=n;
        this.radius=r;
        this.distance=d;
        this.speed=s;
        this.orbitalPeriod=o;
      }



      // add other methods here
      public String getName()
      {
        return name;
      }

      public float getRadius()
      {
        return radius;
      }

      public float getDistance()
      {
        return distance;
      }

      public float getSpeed()
      {
        return speed;
      }

      public float getOrbitalPeriod()
      {
        return orbitalPeriod;
      }

      public void setName(String n)
      {
        this.name=n;
      }

      public void setOrbitalPeriod(int o)
      {
        this.orbitalPeriod=o;
      }

      public String toString()
      {
        return ("Moon : " +name +" "+"orbit="+orbitalPeriod);
      }

      // This will display the moon when other code is completed.  You don't need to understand this code.
      public void display()
      {
        angle=angle+(0.01*speed);
        pushMatrix();
        rotate(angle);
        translate(distance, 0);
        fill(149, 149, 149);
        ellipse(0, 0, radius*2, radius*2);
        popMatrix();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at this function:

```java
public String getMoonName()
{
   return moons[i].getName();
}
```

Where do you think the `i` variable is defined? Your instructions say to take an argument, but this function does not take any arguments.

As a small example, let's say I had this function:

```
public void printMessage(){
   println("Hello!");
}
```

If I wanted to modify that function to take a parameter, I would have to add that to the method like this:

```
public void printMessage(String message){
   println(message);
}
```

You have to do something similar with your `getMoonName()` function.

If you're still stuck, [please post a small example like mine](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of your whole sketch, and we'll go from there.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Kevin Workman, So should it be println instead of return in this function?   `public String getMoonName()
{
   return moons[i].getName();
}`

Comment: @Barry No. My function is just an example. I'm using `println()` as an example. The real point was to show you the argument being passed into the function.

Comment: @Barry You aren't awful. You're just learning. Sometimes it can be a painful process. You just have to take a step back and try to break your problem down into smaller steps.

Comment: I'm on your website now, Is there anything on there that you think could help me? I'm looking at the creating functions page now.

Comment: @Barry Sure, that tutorial contains instructions on creating functions that take arguments. Also, look at my example above: do you notice the part where the function takes an argument? Do you understand what that's doing?

Comment: I think so, It's the parameter that the function will take and inside the the {} is the steps that happens when the function is called. What do you mean when you say argument is that the code inside the ()?

Comment: @Barry Yep, exactly. See how my first `printMessage()` function does not take an argument, but the second one does.